# Exact differential equations, what are we trying to find exactly?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Usually in a normal differential equation such as

$ 2y'' + y' = 3y $

We try to find the solution(s) to this equation by finding a function $y$ such that it satisfies that equation, for this example, one of the solutions is $ y = e^x$ ofcourse.

But now in an exact differential equations there is something that doesn't make sense to me, say I have the multivariable function (and let's assume it's exact)

$M (x,y) + N (x,y) y' = 0$ -----> $ (i)$

While trying to solve for this exact differential equation, we consider the level curve of a function $ \psi (x,y) $ where,

$ d \psi = \frac { \partial \psi}{ \partial x} dx + \frac { \partial \psi}{ \partial y} dy$

$ \frac {d \psi}{dx} = \frac { \partial \psi}{ \partial x} + \frac { \partial \psi}{ \partial y} \frac {dy}{dx}$ ----------> $ (ii)$

And we approach it by comparing $ (i) $ and $ (ii)$

Then when integrating partially w.r.t to $x$ , we treat $y$ as a constant, that means that $y$ is independant on $x$ at the first place, doesn't that mean that $ \frac {dy}{dx} = 0 $ ? Or what am I misunderstanding here?

Comment: Yes, at the point of integrating the functions $M$ or $N$, the variables $x,y$ of this function are considered independent. In the differential equation they are of course not independent, one wants to find a solution to $M(x,y(x))+N(x,y(x))y'(x)=0$. If a first integral $F$ can be computed from $M,N$, then this solution also satisfies $F(x,y(x))=C$.

Comment: I can't grasp this, how can we consider y independent on x if it is already a function of x in the differential equation, can you clarify or suggest me a good source.

Comment: It's just rewriting the solution in an implicit form. Instead of $y=f(x)$, we relate $y$ and $x$ through the equation $F(x,y) = 0$

Comment: "when integrating partially w.r.t to $x$": what do you mean ?

Comment: Integrating $\frac { \partial \psi}{ \partial x} = g(x,y)$ holding $y$ constant, is what I mean. Same goes for $ \partial \psi_y$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the beginning there is the function. $f(x,y)$ or $M(x,y),N(x,y)$. These are just simple functions of two independent variables. You can do with them what you can do with any other function of two variables. Especially you can check if the vector $(M,N)$ is the gradient of some other function $F$, and try to reconstruct the function $F$ by integrating.

Then there is the differential equation. One ingredient to the differential equation is the function(s) as above. In the differential equation you are looking for a dependence $y=\psi(x)$ so that $\frac{dy}{dx}=\psi'(x)=f(x,\psi(x))$. By abuse of notation one often writes directly $y(x)$ instead of $y=\psi(x)$, changing $y$ from a free to a dependent variable. This means that you have two very similar objects named $y$ that occupy the same position, but differ in their dependency.

---

The same goes for the exact equation. In $0=M(x,y)\,dx+N(x,y)\,dy$ the variables are independent, both free. This equation defines a direction field in $\Bbb R^2$, the direction is the line through $(-N,M)$ and its multiples. The solutions are curves whose tangents are elements of the direction field everywhere.

In the formula $0=M(x,y(x))+N(x,y(x))y'(x)$ the variable named $y$ or $y(x)$, an object different from the free variable $y$ above, is again dependent on $x$, the direction field is collapsed to the vector field $(1,-\frac{M}{N})$.

---

At the point of integrating the functions $M$ or $N$ to find a first integral $F$ with $(M,N)=\nabla F$, the variables $x,y$ of these functions are considered independent. In the differential equation they are of course not independent, one wants to find a solution to $M(x,y(x))+N(x,y(x))y′(x)=0$. If a first integral $F$ can be computed from $M,N$, then this solution also satisfies $F(x,y(x))=C$.

Answer (score 1):

A level curve has the equation

$$\psi(x,y)=l$$ where $l$ is the level constant. This expresses a dependency between $x$ and $y$, i.e. an implicit function.

Taking the differential

$$\frac{\partial\psi(x,y)}{\partial x}dx+\frac{\partial\psi(x,y)}{\partial y}dy=0$$ re-states this dependency in terms of the slope of the curve,$\dfrac{dy}{dx}$, by

$$\frac{\partial\psi(x,y)}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial\psi(x,y)}{\partial y}\dfrac{dy}{dx}=0,$$

which is indeed of the form

$$M(x,y)+N(x,y)\dfrac{dy}{dx}=0.$$