# Why write $P(x)dx+Q(y)dy= 0$ instead of $P(x)+Q(y)y'=0$?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, notation

I see ODEs like $P(x)dx+Q(y)dy= 0$ in the context of exact differential equations.

My understanding is that this is another expression of $P(x)+Q(y)y'=0$.

Why write $P(x)dx+Q(y)dy= 0$ instead of $P(x)+Q(y)y'=0$?

Comment: One reason is because it is more “symmetrical” in the roles played by $x$ and $y$. The latter requires you to think of solving for $y$ as a function of $x$, whereas the former allows you to solve for $x,y$ as functions of a third parameter $t$. The reason why the symmetrical role is better is because coordinates are to a large extent arbitrary, so to generalize to other situations (manifolds) we should limit their use.

Comment: This is a frequently asked question, see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3904285/problem-with-understanding-notation-in-exact-differential-equations, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3086854/exact-differential-equations-what-are-we-trying-to-find-exactly, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3141702/exact-differential-equation-geometry

Comment: @KurtG. No. It says "Of course the specific notation is chosen for its connection to differential or Pfaffian forms ..." but does not explain in detail. I am not questioning the meaning of df or dx.

Comment: I disagree that one needs Pfaffians to understand that notation. Choose another duplicate provided by Lutz Lehmann. The notations in your title are equivalent and one does not need deep mathematics to understand that. Separate variables, find integrating factors, and if you doubt anything check that the solution solves the ODE. BTW: in your particular case separating variables is enough.